# How to pause or resume the download using expo react native file system?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, filesystems

I am working on download video using expo file system.

// Download Progress

```
const [progress, setProgress] = useState();
const [percentage, setPercentage] = useState(0);
const [isDownloading, setIsDownloading] = useState(false);
const [downloadStatus, setDownloadStatus] = useState("initial");

// This is the download callback function for detecting the download process
const callback = downloadProgress => {

    const progressBytes =
        downloadProgress.totalBytesWritten /
        downloadProgress.totalBytesExpectedToWrite;

    setProgress(progressBytes);
    setPercentage((progressBytes * 100).toFixed());

    console.log(progressBytes);

    if (progressBytes >= 1 || progressBytes < 0) {
        setProgress(0);
    }

};

// The download functionality.
const downloadFile = async (endpoint, name) => {

    var ext = endpoint.substr(endpoint.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    const downloadResumable = FileSystem.createDownloadResumable(
        endpoint,
        FileSystem.documentDirectory + name + "." + ext,
        {},
        callback
    );

    setIsDownloading(true);


    switch (downloadStatus) {
        case "start":

            try {
                const { uri } = await downloadResumable.downloadAsync();
                saveFile(uri);
                setIsDownloading(false);
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(e);
            }

            break;

        case "pause":

            try {
                await downloadResumable.pauseAsync();
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(e);
            }

            break;

        case "resume":

            try {
                const { uri } = await downloadResumable.resumeAsync();
                saveFile(uri);
                setIsDownloading(false);
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(e);
            }

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

};
```

// This is a function to save the video to gallery

const saveFile = async (uri) => {

```
    const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();

    if (status == "granted") {
        const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(uri);
        MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync("Cinema.af", asset, false)
            .then(() => console.log('File Saved Successfully'))
            .catch(() => console.log('Error in saving file'));
    }

}
```

The download process and save to gallery work fine. But I am not able to add the pause or resume functionalities.
It returns the **no download object** error.
Please Help me.

Answer (score 3):

you can create a downlaodResumable,

```
 let fullPath = FileSystem.documentDirectory + fileLocationName
        downloadResumable = new FileSystem.DownloadResumable(
            linkDownload,
            fullPath,
            downloadSnapshot.options,
            callback, //->this is the callback function 
            downloadSnapshot.resumeData
        );
```

the callback function is something like this:

```
   const callback = (downloadProgress: { totalBytesWritten: number; totalBytesExpectedToWrite: number; }) => {
        const progress = downloadProgress.totalBytesWritten / downloadProgress.totalBytesExpectedToWrite;

        if (!saving && progress * 100 > current + 5) {
            saving = true
            current = progress * 100
            saveAsync(downloadResumable).then(res => {
                resumeAsync(downloadResumable).then(res1 => {
                    saving = false
                })
            })
        }

        try {
            updateProgress(progress)

        } catch (error) {

        }


    };
```

Every 5% i save the status of the download with the async storage

```
    const saveAsync = async (downloadResumable: any) => {
        await downloadResumable.pauseAsync();
        console.log('Paused download operation, saving for future retrieval');
        AsyncStorage.setItem(pathAsync, JSON.stringify(downloadResumable.savable()));

    }
```

and then i can resume it with this funciton:

```
    const resumeAsync = async (downloadResumable: any) => {
        downloadResumable.resumeAsync();

    }
```

If you don't understand something, I can post my entire code that works out of the box, I have some problems with ios but I think I can figure it out.

Comment: Would you please share with me your code like in github? I would be really glad if you do this.